# mysql: update several records with one query

Tags: mysql, database

i am currently using the following query syntax for updating records like the following:

```
update items set sort_index=1 where id=11
update items set sort_index=2 where id=33
update items set sort_index=3 where id=52
```

so i was wondering, is it possible to update several records by ONE single query?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to update multiple records with one query, it however is not possible to update multiple records with different data, all records are updated with the same "SET" criteria.

So the method your currently using is the correct method for updating those records, if you have multiple records that get their sort index updated to 1,2,3 you can collect those ids then run the following to update all collected records

```
UPDATE items set sort_index=1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3); //where 1, 2 and 3 are the ids
```

Comment: Will work when sort_index need to be the same, not in Fuxi question example.

Comment: correct that first para states that, its not possible to what he describes but as an alternative if there are more then one he can group it as shown above

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update row(s) based upon the give `where` expression.